# SwiftUI button position relative to background

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, I'm trying to make a map, and when the user clicks on one of the stops, the info sheet will pop up.

I was going use the map in a ZStack, but how do I place the buttons on top of the stops; how do I define the position of the button so this works in landscape or portrait?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      VStack{
        ZStack {
          Image("background")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
          Button(action: {}) {
          Text("Button")
          }.position(x: 200, y: 150)
        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/4)

        myMasterDetailView()
      }
    }
  }
}

struct myMasterDetailView: View {
  var body: some View {
      GeometryReader { geometry in
          HStack{
              myMasterView()
                  .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height)
                  .background(Color.yellow)
            VStack {
              myDetailView()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height*2/3)
                  .background(Color.orange)
              Text("Comment area")
              .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height/3)
            }
          }
      }
  }
}

struct myMasterView: View {
  var body: some View {
      Text("Master View")
  }
}

struct myDetailView: View {
  var body: some View {
      Text("Detail View")
  }
}
```

Link for background file:  [background.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb9ZQ.png)

Comment: could you add some code to show what you have tried? Here are the instructions on how to provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wasn't sure where to start since I'm just learning, but I knew HStack and VStack wouldn't help.  Since I need the relative placement of the buttons to be the same independent of whether the 11" iPad Pro is landscape or portrait, I didn't think .position would be useful (not to mention time consuming in trying to place the button)

Comment: Look at `ZStack` you can draw stuff on top of each other :)

Comment: Thanks, but ZStack won't let me specifically place an object.  I started looking at alignment grids, but again, still won't let me put a button exactly where I want...

Comment: You can do that with .offset() but I would rather go for VStacks and HStacks in a ZStack

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  When I turn to landscape, the .position moves the button from on top of the cross to further left.  What command keeps it on the cross regardless of device or view?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a powerpoint to help solve this problem.  I put a grid over the image to determine a desired position.  I used an offset based on the geometry:

`geometry.size.width*0.10` moves the button 10% from the center

If the device was an iPad mini or in landscape, then I applied an additional scaling factor.

```
geometry.size.width*0.10*landscapeScaleFactor
```

I couldn't find a way to calculate the scale factor, so just found something acceptable through trial and error.